# How do I close/disable an .ascx control page when logging out?

Tags: c#, asp.net

net creating a website.  When you have logged in with your username and password a control with your profile and search options is created at the top of the page.  When I log out to the login page the control is still there with all the information. (Note in login page the control does not yet exist when 1st login occurs but does after that)  What I want to do is disable or close that control until someone has logged in again.
There seems to be little information about this.

I use  Response.Redirect("Login.aspx"); as well as clearing the information but control still exists.

Should there be modification in the cs or just the ascx or both?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can wrap the usercontrol in an `Asp:Panel` and set it to `Visible="False"` in the onclick event of the logout button.

Comment: agreed. i would use a panel do display it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the control actually *has* the information if the user is logged out, so I think you have a more significant thing to worry about there, but as for a fix for your predicament, you can hide the control on page load:

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
  userSpecificControl.Visible = false;
}
```

Then that control won't be sent down the wire, hence not rendered.

Comment: Good solution! Better then a panel in the usercontrol!